# Mysql ranking with upper and lower rankers

Tags: mysql

I want to get range ranking from a table using mysql query.

the table is like this,

```
+------------+------+
| first_name | age  |
+------------+------+
| Kathy      |   2  |
| Jane       |   1  |
| Nick       |   3  |
| Bob        |   5  |
| Anne       |   4  |
| Jack       |   6  |
| Bill       |   8  |
| Steve      |   7  |
+------------+------+
```

and I want to get Jack's ranking with 2 lower and upper rankers.

```
+------------+------+
| Anne       |   4  |
| Bob        |   5  |
| Jack       |   6  |
| Steve      |   7  |
| Bill       |   8  |
+------------+------+
```

Any idea how to write this query for a MySQL database?

Comment: What if Anne and Bob are 5 (old)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a very ugly way to do this by applying a rownumber to the records.  By applying the rownumber to the records, then you you will be able to return rows if the ages are not consecutive (Demo with [Non-consecutive ages](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f7d4/1)):

```
select age, first_name
from 
(
  select t1.age, t1.first_name, @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS rownum
  from yourtable t1, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
  order by t1.age
) x
where rownum  >= (select rownum
                  from 
                  (
                    select t.age, 
                      t.first_name, 
                      @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS rownum
                    from yourtable t, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
                    order by t.age
                  ) x
                  where first_name = 'jack') - 2
 and rownum  <= (select rownum
                    from 
                    (
                      select t.age, 
                        t.first_name, 
                        @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS rownum
                      from yourtable t, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
                      order by t.age
                    ) x
                    where first_name = 'jack') + 2;
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21209/2)

Comment: If he doesn't have an id column, this is the correct solution.  Nice job bluefeet. +1

Comment: good job with great efforts. and yes it's really ugly. ^^; are there no problem to use query safe in a real product. Rank query have to be called frequently.

Comment: @JinbomHeo I am currently using rownumber in several queries in my application with no issues.  Things will be much easier once MySQL supports windowing functions.

Answer (score 1):

Working Example:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE id BETWEEN ((SELECT id FROM yourtable WHERE name = 'Jack') - 2) AND ((SELECT id FROM yourtable WHERE name = 'Jack') + 2);
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7f1f6/3)

Comment: I thought this initially but this will not work if the ages are non-consecutive, unless there is some other field that makes the records consecutive.

Comment: Correct, though I'm not sure if that's an issue.  Not sure what he's trying to do, though he should have some kind of ordering.  He probably is looking for a type of GROUP BY query

Comment: maybe, you mean -2. but, in real table age can be vary. not just +1 increment.

Comment: Crap, I didn't realize the the answer table was in order. shyte.